# can some one recommend a good client library to send data over https?

Tags: javascript, https, client

Hello I'm familiar with a node js api for gdax.com to make market transactions. However the api is for node. I do not wish to make a webserver but instead a client side. I am familiar with https so is there a client version of https connection that I can make get request, maybe start a webssl, where I handle application layer to https. Kinda like client side java script version of c openssl or what ever its called, secure sockets.

Comment: Or even if someone knows a client js implementation of gdax rest api?

Comment: The [help/on-topic] says *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow*.

Comment: Must be a tough question

Comment: That's absurd there are literally millions of questions so it goes against the precedence established.

Comment: I've already quoted from (and linked to) the [help/on-topic]. Read it yourself. The guidelines have been in place for years that prohibit this sort of question. In fact, Jeff wrote a blog post about it, and he hasn't been here for years. The *precedence* has been to *not* accept these sorts of question. Requests to change the policy have gone through discussion at [meta] and rejected on many occasions. You want to complain? Take it to [meta].

Comment: This isn't a specific issue with source code, this is asking for recommendations which can be opinion based... opinion based questions are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's not opinion based, what basic api is used to send https messages. I have worked it out, it was confusing cause answers typically also involve nodejs as the askers are writing the server as well as the client applications served. But I figure the answer is socket.io and creating the socket with https will handle the ssl/tls stuff. Sorry if I phrased poorly but I don't ask what is a "good" tool, but what tools, any tools that allow me to send restful requests over https.

Comment: *" I don't ask what is a "good" tool"* ... read your title. *"can some one **recommend** a **good**"* Asking for recommendation is based on ones opinion of it being good hence that person recommending it which means that recommendation is based on their opinion. I think researching would be a better option than asking on Stack Overflow unless you were already attempting to use something but wasn't happy with the outcome.

Comment: Further seems kinda fundamental to java script. Any webpage that isn't static, needs to communicate with the server, and to even run in most common browser, it is required to be https. So anyone that has ever used java script to make a web page that does anything dynamically like io, or update does it through an https socket, no?

Comment: No. Not everyone uses https or websockets. Some websites with dynamic data will be over http and use ajax to make server requests to then use that data to build those dynamic elements. Once again, it all depends on the expectations of the website and what that developers outcome expectations are.

Comment: Chrome browser does not allow http

Comment: Ajax is more abstract layer than https. It still use the socket (ip address + port for https) it then would say upgrade for webspcket upgrade to a wss

Comment: Also @NewToJs that is pedantic, was (webspcket) is on https ofen even on https socket (though it has a different designated port/socket it is upgraded from an https/http). Sure also http could be used but as I said it would not be compatible with a google chrome browser. Also, I have seen questions just today about PayPal rest API, essentially perfect analogy, but this question is valued and upvoted whilst mine heavily hated. So again this is a random outburst pf seemingly random hate. It does go against stackexcjange presidence, right or wrong. Anyways I solved it, no thanks to you.

Comment: Using same techniques as the PayPal API would or anyother java script rest web application. When I get code in presentable state I will github it and link.

Comment: So go ahead and down vote, I already can no longer ask questions cause of you. Well obviously I can answer some and help people, maybe even you one day, but being as its not fair for me to help others while not receiving help cause of block I won't use this site anymore. So enjoy your points answering java script which you are clearly inexperienced at and unable to help, not because of lack of knowledge but your ego and hatefulness to good questions, obviously you learned something cause you didn't know answer. So your welcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used XMLHTTPRequest(). Seems pretty standard now and obvious for REST API. WebSocket() object for was.